# excel: filter using formulas

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have a list of people who belong to two groups (A or B). I want to create a column which lists all the people who belong to group A.
I have been trying to come up with an array formula but I do not have a working example. Any help appreciated!

Names | Group | Desired Output

Bob   | A | Bob

Fred | B | Eric

Matt | B | Dave

Eric | A | Fred

Dave | A |
Stew | B |
Fred | A |

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal formula for column C:

```
C2=
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B="A"),ROW()-1)), "")
```

Copy/paste down in column `C` for a sufficient number of cells.

Array formula: select a sufficient number of cells in column `C` and write the same formula in the formula bar then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: thanks, I tried this one, but I get a division by zero inside the row function. the true/false array loads, as does the row function but the division fails. any ideas?

Comment: hello, I got this one to work eventually by changing the offset. However I use this formula often and it is slowing down my whole sheet, and it takes a long time to evaluate when I try to step through it. Any ideas on how to make it more efficient. I have been trying to shrink the range by using a range reference instead of the entire column but I cant get it to work.

Comment: @Freelancer try like this: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$100)/($B$1:$B$100="A"),ROW()-1)), "")`. Also try not putting it in a too large number of cells, just what is sufficient to get all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

From this

```
+---+-------+-------+
|   |   A   |   B   |
+---+-------+-------+
| 1 | Name  | Group |
| 2 | Nick  | A     |
| 3 | Marc  | A     |
| 4 | Manny | B     |
| 5 | Luck  | A     |
+---+-------+-------+
```

you can create two pivot tables with Name in the row label and Group in the filter data.
Then you can filter only people depending on the group.

```
+---+-------------------+---+
|   |         A         | B |
+---+-------------------+---+
| 1 | Group             | A |
| 2 |                   |   |
| 3 | Etichette di riga |   |
| 4 | Luck              |   |
| 5 | Marc              |   |
| 6 | Nick              |   |
+---+-------------------+---+
```

Comment: thanks but I need to reference it dynamically later on. I need cells to reference not a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

So if your data is in range `A1:B7` this would be the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$7="A",ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

This is array formula that is applied with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` and you will need to drag it down.

Comment: thanks, when I try this, I only get the same value populated in the entire formula array, the first line. any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that you applied it with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. Because your issue is real only if you use just `Enter`.